# How to implement English Dictionary Word in Prediction for Android Application?

Tags: android, dictionary, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, prediction

i am creating my keyboard for android and want to give text Prediction functionality like `android's default keyboard`,
i have goggled the things but still there is no standard method i have found..

What i have done yet is to give `USER_DICTIONARY`.
but now want to give `English dictionary` word in prediction.

So can anybody guide me for that or can give some useful links regarding `algorithm` or anything will be helpfull for me.

Hope I will have some help soon..

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a solution to this problem based on the paper mentioned [here](http://arnab.org/tag/prediction)
The paper is quite readable and has the details of the algorithm.

For details of suffix tree refer to this [article](http://marknelson.us/1996/08/01/suffix-trees/)